# Regex validation code for excel file upload jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, excel

how to validate excel files

**My JQuery**

```
 jQuery("#excel").validate({
      expression: "if (VAL.match(/^([a-z]\w*)\.(xls[mx]?)$/) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
      message: "Please upload valid excel file"
 });
```

Comment: Aren't numbers allowed in excel filenames?

Comment: @thomas, yes Name numbers and special characters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should change an order in expression, since you don’t want to execute expression on invalid `VAL`:

```
VAL && VAL.match(/^([a-z]\w*)(.xlsx|.xlsm|.xls)
```

Secondary, any `\w` symbol is perfectly valid as starting symbol for filename, as well, as a dot and space (and, possibly, some other symbols.) Dots in regexps should be escaped. And, a last but not least, you could want to compact the `xls*`s:

```
/^([\w\s.]*)\.xls[xm]?$/
```

Comment: it won't work if the file-name contains any special characters.

Comment: Really? You think copy-pasting my arguments under my answer is the proper way to help OP?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654466/regex-validation-code-for-excel-file-upload-jquery#comment43725413_27654473) . If you have any queries, ask it to the op . He didn't mention about the spaces or dots in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dots.

```
^([a-z]\w*)(\.xlsx|\.xlsm|\.xls)$
```

OR

```
^([a-z]\w*)\.(xls[mx]?)$
```

`[mx]?` matches an optional `m` or `x`

Use this regex if you want to allow any characters inbetween `^([a-z].*)\.(xls[mx]?)$`

Comment: This fails on `abc.def.xls` and any file containing space in the name.

Comment: then this `^([a-z].*)\.(xls[mx]?)$`

Comment: It was not me who downvoted, but let me guess: because you provide the wrong answer.

Comment: Because this answer is working better than what OP introduced _only_ on files having trailing `xls*` as not extension.

Comment: could provide some examples for this?

Comment: @AvinashRaj i have updated my question with JSbin. can u help me?